# Wrong OO architecture, sharing objects and dependencies? Maybe i'm missing a design pattern here?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

OK, i'm creating a small PHP application. The current structure is something like this:

```
$client = new AppName\Client;
$model = $client->getModel();
$model->getNode();
```

Everything is beautiful here. Client is responsible for connecting and running commands through Socket to a small C application i built. I'm just playing with architecture here. Client::getModel returns an instance of Model. During getModel, i inject Client inside Model through the constructor. Something like this:

```
public function getModel()
{
    return new Model('parameter', $this);
}
```

Which, in turn...

```
// Model
public function __construct($param, Client $client)
{
    $this->setClient($client);
    // ...
}
```

However, during Model::getNode, i want to return an instance of Node. However, unlike getModel, i don't want to inject Client again. But i have to. Right now, i'm doing this:

```
public function getNode()
{
    return new Node('parameter', $this->getClient());
}
```

I'm sure this isn't correct. There must be something that i'm missing... i understand and use Dependency Injection, but i'm quite sure a Dependency Injection Container will not solve my problem.

Comment: one simple way is to extend modal and create node. ie. something like: class node extends modal{} this way you can access public/protected modal vars of modal in node

Comment: What is your question? The design looks fine for me

Comment: Class hierarchy should have nothing to do with dependencies.

Comment: Seems fine to me aswell. One thing to keep in mind is that objects are always passed by reference, so no matter how many times you have to inject the object around, it will always be the same copy responding to every other object (which in the end is what you want to achieve I assume)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really speak to your entire design because you didn't post most of it, but I think there is a pattern you are missing.  One of the core OO design principles is that you don't ask an object for data/objects and then operate on that data/object, you ask an object to DO something for you--perhaps that part was just edited for brevity, but you might want to consider doing less "Getting".

In order to force this in my own design I NEVER create setters and getters on the first pass (Well, I pretty much NEVER create setters at all).  Later I will go in and add getters only when I can't avoid them (you do still need them quite often I think...)

Another thing is to completely avoid inheritance until you are absolutely it's the only way to solve a problem without duplicating code or making things confusing.  Problem is, the question isn't coded in my native language so I really can't tell what all you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to store the client in the model inside setClient() or you are not returning it from getClient()

If you would post the code for setClient() and getClient() I could verify that.

```
setClient($client){
    $this->client = $client;
}

getClient(){
    return $this->client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the Model's job to get the client (or vice versa!). That's the factory's problem! Your methods should look like so:

```
$client = new AppName\Client($model);
```

You should never mix factory logic with your business logic, as it makes testing impossible.

Comment: It's wrong to instance the Client everywhere, that's what DI is for.

Comment: @vinnylinux: My point exactly. You shouldn't be doing what your `Client::getModel()` does.

Comment: I believe you are confusing my Model with an MVC model? It has nothing to do, it's just an example.

Comment: @vinny you don't understand what I'm saying. Don't have your client instantiate a new model object, inject it instead. It doesn't matter whether it's MVC or not. Don't mix factory and business logic.

Comment: Inject from where, since Client is responsible for creating this object?